# Can Mylar be hacked?

Tags: security, meteor

I'm interested in using [Mylar](http://css.csail.mit.edu/mylar/) for an upcoming project.

The promises that Mylar makes seem impressive. However, could a dev write a back-door attack into the code, that is allowed to run (verified by hash/signature), so that the data is compromised (likely via XSS)? Mylar documentation states:

> "Mylar ensures that client-side application code is authentic, even if
>   the server is malicious."

The only way I can imagine this being protected against is for the browser itself to disallow outbound communication of unencrypted data. But, for that to happen, how can the app query the database, make calls back to the server (I understand that Mylar is best used with a browser side framework like Meteor, but still, Meteor needs to communicate with the server for certain tasks).

Is Mylar able to provide complete data security, even from the application developer/server admin?

Here is Mylar's claim (from http://www.mit.edu/~ralucap/mylar.pdf):

> 3.4 Threat model
>
> **Threats.** Both the application and the database servers can be fully controlled by an adversary: the adversary may obtain all data
>   from the server, cause the server to send arbitrary responses to web
>   browsers, etc. This model subsumes a wide range of real-world security
>   problems, from bugs in server software to insider attacks. Mylar also
>   allows some user machines to be controlled by the adversary, and to
>   collude with the server. This may be either because the adversary is a
>   user of the application, or because the adversary broke into a user’s
>   machine. We call this adversary active, in contrast to a passive
>   adversary that eavesdrops on all information at the server, but does
>   not make any changes, so that the server responds to all client
>   requests as if it were not compromised.
>
> **Guarantees.** Mylar protects a data item’s confidentiality in the face of arbitrary server compromises, as long as none of the users
>   with access to that data item use a compromised machine.

In this context, 'compromised machine' means the client machine/browser.

---

After re-reading the [Mylar white paper](http://www.mit.edu/~ralucap/mylar.pdf), I see where the document states:

> **Assumptions.** To provide the above guarantees, Mylar makes the
>   following assumptions. Mylar assumes that the web application as
>   written by the developer will not send user data or keys to
>   untrustworthy recipients, *and cannot be tricked into doing so by
>   exploiting bugs (e.g., cross-site scripting)*. Our prototype of Mylar
>   is built on top of Meteor, a framework that helps programmers avoid
>   many common classes of bugs in practice.

Does this mean the way the application was written at the time of encryption, or at the time of attack? In other words, is the encrypted data somehow tied to a specific version of the application code? Elsewhere in the [referenced Mylar white paper](http://www.mit.edu/~ralucap/mylar.pdf) it indicates that the app code is verified against a hash signature.

If the app code can simply be hacked at the server, this reduces the value proposition greatly, as any attacker who gains access to the source code could modify the code and leach data as it is requested (at the browser). The Guarantee of "protecting confidentiality in the face of arbitrary server compromises" seems broad enough to include the idea of the attacker modifying the source code of the application, hence my confusion.

---

Also refer to section 6 in the white paper for more information. I believe the Mylar doc is conveying that it does mitigate compromised application code attacks. I'd really love to hear from a dev with authoritative understanding of Mylar.

Comment: Grubbs (2017): Why Your Encrypted Database Is Not Secure: https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/468.pdf

Answer (score 3):

> *... could a dev write a back-door attack into the code, that is allowed to run (verified by hash/signature), so that the data is compromised (likely via XSS)?*

**Yes, a developer could write a back-door into the code**. There is no way to prevent that, because a developer could claim he's using Mylar although he doesn't or does use a compromised version. Note that Mylar doesn't say, it could prevent that. **It's preventing attacks by server operators**, for example if you host your application in a third-party cloud.

> 3 MYLAR ARCHITECTURE
>
> There are three different parties in Mylar: the users, the web site owner, and the server operator.  Mylar’s goal is to help the site owner protect the confidential data of users in the face of a malicious or compromised server operator.

If you don't trust the developers or web site owner, you have to check the client-side source code very time it's loaded.

---

> *Mylar documentation states: "Mylar ensures that client-side application code is authentic, even if the server is malicious."*
>
> *The only way I can imagine this being protected against is for the browser itself to disallow outbound communication of unencrypted data. But, for that to happen, how can the app query the database, make calls back to the server* [...]
>
> *Is Mylar able to provide complete data security, even from the application developer/server admin?*

That's right, **the browser won't send unencrypted data to the server** (at least the data which you marked as secret). I can't provide a full explanation for how it allows a large subset of SQL functionality on encrypted data, because it's complicated. [As Raluca Ada Popa explains in one of her presentations](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/CS5412/2014sp/slides/XXIV%20-%20Attack.pdf), data is encrypted several times with different algorithms, because each algorithm allows different operations on encrypted data (equality check, ordering, text search, ...). The MIT institute also developed [CryptDB](http://css.csail.mit.edu/cryptdb/), which uses the same methodology but only protects the database server.

---

> > *3.4 Threat model*: *Both the application and the database servers can be fully controlled by an adversary* [...]

When an attacker controls the application server, he could exchange the whole application with his own, which mocks the original user interface. Here comes the browser plugin into play: The application is signed by the web site owner before it's deployed, so that **the browser plugin may check the signature and alarm the user if the application was modified**.

You might have noticed that Mylar needs the user to check authenticity himself. Other things that an user needs to be aware of:

- Mylar applications must be loaded over a secure HTTPS connection.
- Retrieved data must be signed by the expected user (for example a chat room must show who created it and the user has to check if someone tries to fake an existing room).
- The client machine must not compromised.
- ...

---

> > *Mylar assumes that the web application as written by the developer will not send user data or keys to untrustworthy recipients, and cannot be tricked into doing so by exploiting bugs (e.g., cross-site scripting)*.
>
> *Does this mean the way the application was written at the time of encryption, or at the time of attack?*

They assume the application as delivered doesn't contain any bugs which could leak private data. **Mylar doesn't prevent coding mistakes, it prevents untrusted modifications later on.**

> *In other words, is the encrypted data somehow tied to a specific version of the application code? Elsewhere in the [referenced Mylar white paper](http://www.mit.edu/~ralucap/mylar.pdf) it indicates that the app code is verified against a hash signature.*
>
> *If the app code can simply be hacked at the server, this reduces the value proposition greatly, as any attacker who gains access to the source code could modify the code and leach data as it is requested (at the browser).*

Encrypted data isn't tied to a specific version. Each version of the application needs to be signed by the web site owner, so that the browser plugin may check it's signature and attacks would be obvious to users. **A common dynamic web site wouldn't allow signing**, because each user data is different and would modify the received code, therefore **application code (HTML, JavaScript, ..) and data are strictly separated**. After the application is loaded and it's signature was checked, data is retrieved via AJAX, whereas the AJAX response must not contain executable code (this is part of the [Meteor framework](http://www.meteor.com/), I can't tell anything about it).

---

**Conclusion**

- If the web site owner himself is dishonest, you can't be sure about privacy. This is especially the case if governments are able to force the web site owner to cooperate.
- Also Mylar doesn't prevent bugs, which could leak data. For example the simplest mistake would be that a developer forgot to mark a field as private.
- When an attacker overtakes the application server, users are warned, but if they ignore it (for example they didn't install the browser plugin) their data could be intercepted.
- If you want to outsource hosting of your application or you won't trust your own server operators, **Mylar provides better security than any other framework** I know of.

Comment: Let's assume the app code has passed QC, is signed, and stores encrypted data; later, a hacker gains full control of the server and alters the code to include and XSS attack, or otherwise, the app is then run, the hack does it's job, and the data is stolen. Is this scenario a possibility? Sorry, this is the part that I remain confused about. I guess I'm asking how the browser plugin understands if the application has been legitimately altered vs. hacked?

Comment: @RogerRoger The attacker doesn't have the key to sign it, therefore the application becomes either unsigned or uses the old sign which is now invalid. (The sign is like a checksum of the code, change a single character and you'll get another checksum.) Both cases will be detected by the browser plugin. But the attacker may steal data of users, who don't use the plugin.